# Why did Facebook blacklist my website?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, links, website, blacklist

I have a site helpmen.org which I use to sell domain names.  I used to link to it from my Facebook page, but now it's blacklisted and all posts featuring it have been automatically removed.  Since my domains redirect to the site, that's most of my posts.  Facebook is the same obnoxious anti-user company it's always been, so I cant get any answer from them.

One possibility I've come up with (not at all sure it's the case) is Facebook not liking the amount of links to the site.  However, I don't spam and don't post repeatedly.
The other possibility I can see is a FB admin viewing the site as a sort of landing page (which it is in part) and disliking that.  The blacklist was soon after I changed the name of the page, which required review.  Could that have prompted it?

I don't believe there's any good reason for the blacklist but since there's no arguing (or communicating) with Facebook, does anyone know from personal experience with Facebook Pages or general Facebook knowledge what could be the reason for this blacklist?